# Would Deut 33:20 be considered an example of compound direct objects in Hebrew?

Tags: hebrew, grammatical-object

**The Hebrew for Deuteronomy 33:20 reads:**
וּלְגָד אָמַר בָּרוּךְ מַרְחִיב גָּד כְּלָבִיא שָׁכֵן וְטָרַף זְרוֹעַ אַף־קָדְקֹד

**The English translation (KJV) for Deuteronomy 33:20 reads:**
And of Gad he said, Blessed be he that enlargeth Gad: he dwelleth as a lion, and teareth the arm with the crown of the head.

From my understanding of the English translation, "arm" and "crown" are both direct objects of the transitive verb "teareth." Is this an accurate assessment, and does this hold true for the Hebrew text (i.e., Is it fair to say that "זְרוֹעַ" and "קָדְקֹד" are compound direct objects of the verb "וְטָרַף")? Also, is there an official term for verbs that act on compound direct objects? Thanks!